# Timing chain issue

Tags: ford, explorer, timing

I'm working on a **2002 Ford Explorer XLT 4.0 2WD 6cyc SOHC gas**

And I just so happened to break the chain tensioner, yup. You heard it right. As if I didn't hit enough stripped bolts along the way. The tensioner broke both pieces at the very bottom. So the whole tensioner came out in two whole pieces, they were both connected to each other at the very bottom... I swear these things are so cheap they could of broke if a fly went the wrong way...

> so my question is, can I JB weld or use some type of epoxy, resin or leave the rubber band on it on this chain tensioner, or is it possible to just leave  the guide off ?

If you view the picture you'll notice that this vehicle has no timing marks, it requires a special tool, but the to remove the tensioner it's just below (inside) of the transmission, which requires the whole engine to come out

[image]

these two pieces connect to each other, and even though the right piece looks connected to the engine, its broken at the very bottom with the second piece

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the tensioner has broken in two you'll need to replace it I'm afraid. They aren't mega bucks for those and bodging it back together is just putting a timebomb in place IMHO.

Comment: like literally, it'll explode or ? why wouldn't a strong epoxy work, it's only a guide right

Comment: Explode! really, no but if the chain looses tension, it then slips and the valves meet the pistons damaging the engine... Fine if you want to do a top end rebuild...

Comment: @Solar Mike how can it slip, It's pretty secure on the 2 sprockets with the side tensioner, Then these guides don't really do anything but guide it

Comment: @hellomotto well not in that big fireball way that cool guys walk away from and don't look at but when/if it fails with the engine running it's going to do all sorts of unpleasantly expensive things to the engine.

Comment: Well maybe, perhaps i can remove that guide hex bolt with some long needle node vise grips so the engine wont have to be removed

Comment: @hellomotto "these guides don't really do anything but guide it" while it's *technically* true to say that referring to it as simply "guiding" the chain understates the importance of it's role by more than a little. This is how the tension is applied to the chain, if/when it fails it's no longer going to be applying the correct tension to the chain - thus it can throw the timing out and expensive oily bits will start colliding in ways that they aren't meant to. A replacement "guide" is < $100, a top end rebuild is measured in the thousands.

Comment: @hellomotto - Also realize, the Explorers of these years were nicknamed "Exploder" for a reason. These engines are known for giving up the ghost what seems relatively early in the life cycle. Don't give it a reason to give up on life. Replace the guides and it will be much happier, hopefully giving you a much greater lifespan.

Comment: I don't disagree, but you guys are talking about "a cheap part", however the labor on replacing it is the big pain point.  Pulling an engine out is where most hobby mechanics are going to draw the line, so this realistically could turn into a >$1000 job.  And as far as epoxy or something along those lines - even if that did work perfectly, I don't see how you'd get all the oil-soaked parts clean enough to attempt it.

Comment: It's not that I wouldn't want to pull the engine, it's that I don't want to buy a hoist for a one time use , so I'm hoping to find a skinny pair of vise grips or an easier way to change it without buying a hoist. I can touch the removable bolt but there's some stupid engine bulge right over the top of it, maybe a rag under it and a screwdriver and hammer to turn the nut back 1/4 of an inch would give me plenty of room.